# EazyBI - Why is it not counting up my custom calculated measure?

Tags: mdx

I have a calculated measure that sets up a flag of 1 if it meets a certain condition. It counts all the 1's if I use the total, but when I minimize all the issues, it doesn't count the 1's in the project. I've tried changing the formatting to integer and decimal but still doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

This is what my measure looks like:

```
    CASE
      WHEN [Measures].[Hours spent] <= [Measures].[Time Expectation (h)]
      THEN 1
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

The comparison of "Hours spent" and "Time Expecation (h)" values is performed in the issue level only when you have it in the report. Once you collapse the *Issue* dimension to the "Project" or "All issues" level, the comparison is made in that level. As your calculated measure doesn't have an *ELSE* branch when the condition is not met, it returns empty.

To get the desired values, try the formula below:

```
CASE WHEN
    [Issue].CurrentHierarchyMember.Level.Name = 'Issue'
THEN
    CASE
        WHEN [Measures].[Hours spent] <= [Measures].[Time Expectation (h)]
        THEN 1
    END
ELSE
    Sum(
        Filter(
            -- iterate through Issue dimension "Issue" level
            Descendants([Issue].CurrentMember,[Issue].[Issue]),
            -- return a set of issues matching condition
            [Measures].[Hours spent] <= [Measures].[Time Expectation (h)]
        ),
        -- evaluate the set of issues over the measure below
        [Measures].[Issues with hours spent]
    )
END
```